# Lightswitch pre process query

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a relationship between a `Job` and a `JobStatus`. A Job belongs to a project and a job must a have a project. I am extending functionality where a user can select what Job Statuses they can have in the jobs for that project.

I am able to do that by having a mapping table and using a pre process query.

```
  partial void IsStatusInProject_PreprocessQuery(int? ProjectId, ref IQueryable<JobStatus> query)
        {
             query = query.Where(x => x.ProjectJobStatusCollection.Any(y => y.Project.Id == ProjectId));
        }
```

I have applied a choice to the drop down list for that job, where it gets the statuses they have selected. However, I want to bring back all the statuses if they don't select anything.

How can I extend the pre-process query to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check that the count of ProjectJobStatus for the ProjectId is zero(0) apply no where clause.

Something like this: (Loose pseudo)

```
If (ProjectJobStatus.Where(y => y.ProjectJobStatusCollection.Any(y => y.Project.Id == ProjectId))).Count > 0) {
    query = query.Where(x => x.ProjectJobStatusCollection.Any(y => y.Project.Id == ProjectId));
}
// else { // Do nothing. }
```

Once again, this is partly pseudo code, i haven't bothered to test it or check my syntax!!

Comment: Hey Kris , I tried doing that didnt work it cant convert to bool. I tried this:query = query.Where(x => x.ProjectJobStatusCollection.Count() > 0 && x.ProjectJobStatusCollection.Any(y => y.Project.Id == ProjectId));

Comment: Im using a many to many control I dont know if linq can pick up the collection of a many to many control

Comment: It looks like you're close, the path you're taking should get you the same result.  The path i suggested works like this: If you don't modify the query, it will return everything.

Comment: if (ProjectJobStatusSet.Where(x => x.Project.ProjectJobStatusCollection.Any(y => y.Project.Id == ProjectId)).Count() > 0)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.ProjectJobStatusCollection.Any(y => y.Project.Id == ProjectId));
            }
            else
            {
                query = from q in query
                        select q;
            }

Comment: This was the code that ended up doing the job I owe you a beer mate cheers